# Select2 Search Input box Type

Tags: jquery, laravel, jquery-select2

I am using [Select2](https://select2.org) with Laravel. My Search of [Select2](https://select2.org) is not working.

[image]

My code is like below.

```
$('#restaurant').select2({
            ajax: {
                url: '{{url('/')}}/admin/vendor/get-restaurants',
                data: function (params) {
                    return {
                        q: params.term, // search term
                        all:true,
                        page: params.page
                    };
                },
                processResults: function (data) {
                    return {
                        results: data
                    };
                },
                __port: function (params, success, failure) {
                    var $request = $.ajax(params);

                    $request.then(success);
                    $request.fail(failure);

                    return $request;
                }
            }
        });
```

Here is the function of the controller.

```
public function get_restaurants(Request $request){
        $zone_ids = isset($request->zone_ids)?(count($request->zone_ids)>0?$request->zone_ids:[]):0;
        
        $data = Restaurant::join('zones', 'zones.id', '=', 'restaurants.zone_id')
        ->when($zone_ids, function($query) use($zone_ids){
            $query->whereIn('restaurants.zone_id', $zone_ids);
        })
        ->where('restaurants.name', 'like', '%'.$request->q.'%')
        ->limit(8)
        ->orderBy('restaurants.name', 'ASC')
        ->get([DB::raw('restaurants.id as id, CONCAT(restaurants.name, " (", zones.name,")") as text')]);
        
        if(isset($request->all))
        {
            $data[]=(object)['id'=>'all', 'text'=>'All'];
        }
        return response()->json($data);
    }
```

If I write any thing in Input Search Box it is not working.

Comment: The issue is likely related to JavaScript, JQuery or CSS. Can you share a screenshot of your brower console when the page is loaded

Comment: Thanks @EmekaMbah. Here is the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/lb7H2.png

Comment: So results are loaded with Ajax, but it's not selecting? Do you filter it in your get-restaurants route? Could you share it as well?

Comment: did you implement filtering in Laravel `{{url('/')}}/admin/vendor/get-restaurants` method?

Comment: You need to write a method in Laravel controller that takes the parameters `q: params.term` and filter records based on that

Comment: Thanks @EmekaMbah. I edited my post. Please check it and find the function of the controller.

Comment: Thanks @StewieSWS. Here is the route `Route::get('get-restaurants', 'VendorController@get_restaurants')->name('get-restaurants');`.

Comment: Have you tested `get_restaurants` with postman or by calling the url from your browser. does it work ?

Comment: Thanks @EmekaMbah. It's not a API request.

Comment: That's okay, try going through browser `yoursite.com/admin/vendor/get-restaurants?q=ad` just to be sure it returns the right data

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is the problem with your code however I will tell you my way to do it.

It's very simple just loop over your resturants variable in select and in your script just init the select2.

**In blade file:**

```
<select id="restaurant">
   @foreach($resturants as $resturant)
      <option value="{{ $resturant->id }}">{{ $resturant->name }}</option>
   @endforeach
</select>
```

**In script**

```
$('#restaurant').select2();
```

Comment: Thanks @Mohammed_40. You can check my screenshot. If I type anything the values are not sorting.